# Hide Rendering in a Sitecore placeholder

Tags: sitecore

I have a placeholder in a sublayout and have placed a rendering within the placeholder as below.

```
    <sc:placeholder key="drawTimer" ID="drawTimer" placeholder="drawTimer" runat="server" />'
```

How can I hide the rendering within that placeholder programatically?

Thanks

Comment: so you want to hide a rendering inside the placeholder, not the entire placeholder?

Comment: yes i have got a rendering and sublayout within a placeholder.

Comment: The design has changed. So I would like to hide the placeholder rather than the rendering since it would be 2 complicated to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**:

If all you want to do is hide the placeholder than it can be hidden like any other .NET control.

```
drawTimer.Visible = false;
```

---

One option would be to perform the logic that decides if the rendering should be shown in the rendering itself and just return nothing if it's not meant to be shown.

Depending on what the logic is it might be beneficial to use the rules engine to hide the rendering: http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/Sitecore-Rules-Engine-and-Conditional-Rendering.aspx

I assume the rendering is added in Sitecore. A third option would be to instead add the rendering in code only when the specific conditions are met.